# Instance method alloc not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I wrote this code. I followed the sample application code provided with facebook SDK.
In FeceAppDelegate.m

```
#import "FaceAppDelegate.h"

#import "FaceViewController.h"

@implementation FaceAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize navigationController=_navigationController;

@synthesize facebook;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    FaceViewController *FaceViewController = [[FaceViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:FaceViewController];
       // Initialize Facebook
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"345678" andDelegate:FaceViewController];


    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When I run, I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS , and i have a warning , "Instance method alloc not found ..." 
I think the problem is in

```
FaceViewController *FaceViewController = [[FaceViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: you should have a lower case f at the beginning of the variable name, e.g. FaceViewController *faceViewController = [[FaceViewController alloc] init]; other than that, could you post the header declaration for FaceViewController?

Comment: can u put breakpoints & see which line is giving this problem

Comment: Oh I'm stupid, thank you MCannon , it work with lower case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the first comment is the right answer. When you do:

```
FaceViewController *FaceViewController = [[FaceViewController alloc] init];
```

You've redefined `FaceViewController` to be an instance variable within the current scope so `alloc` is being sent to the instance which doesn't have a an `alloc` method. Change your instance var name and it will work. The convention is to start with lower case for variable names e.g. `faceViewController`.